# Using reference variable to point to a Comparator?

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I ran into a new way of creating `Comparator` while doing exercises. Can anyone explain this a little bit?

```
class Checker{    
    public Comparator<Player> desc = new Comparator<Player>() {
        public int compare(Player A, Player B){
            if(A.score < B.score){
                return 1;
            }
            else if(A.score == B.score){
                return B.name.compareTo(A.name);
            }
            else{
                return -1;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In the past, I have only seen people doing this:

```
class Checker implements Comparator{
    @Override
    public int compare(Player A, Player B){
        ..........
        ..........
    }
}
```

So the first example really seems novel to me(because I am a beginner?). It does make sense: *desc* could be an property/instance variable of class `Checker` which points to a new instance of `Comparator` class/interface. However **are there more stories behind these two different ways of doing things**? They all require creating a different class so I don't see how either one could be more organized.

Comment: Are you sure that you seen `implements Comparator<T>` and not `implements Comparator` (without `<T>`)? `compare(Object o1, Object o2)` would be fine in pre-generic era (pre Java 5) where we couldn't specify which type precisely compare should expect.

Comment: @Pshemo Sorry I made the change! But I do wonder though, why don't we need a <t> to specify type when implementing it for a new class?

Comment: @Pshemo so is the first type of creating comparators very common too? I just have never seen it before on many webs when I searched "Comparator Java"

Comment: @whales Typically you'd see a class called `CheckerComparator` that implements `Comparator<Checker>` rather than it being embedded as you illustrated above.

Comment: I'm wondering what actually confuses you. Are you asking about `Comparator` vs `Comparator<Person>`? Or are you more interested in anonymous class vs standard classes which implements comparable?

Comment: @Pshemo got it. thanks! (Anonymous class)

Comment: Both ways are quite common, especially now in Java 8 where we can create Comparators like `Comparator<Person> ageComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge);`. Or `personList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the syntax are absolutely correct. In first case you are simply using concept of **anonymous class**. In second you created a class Checker which **implements** compare method.

As a beginner it is much easier to understand second syntax other than that there is no difference between the two.

You can study more about anonymous class here -

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

If you want to use comparator at more places its better to use solution in separate class than anonymous one. Anonymous vs class solution is something like inline css style vs style classes.